# Python TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Tags: python

```
import argparse
import pathlib
import sys
from alive_progress import alive_bar


def get_raw_data(path, string):
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        lines = sum(1 for _ in f)
    with open(path, "r") as data:
        results = []
        print(f"Number of lines: {lines}\n")
        with alive_bar(lines, dual_line=True, title="Analyzing") as bar:
            for line in data: 
                if string in line:
                    results.append(line)
                    bar()
                else:
                    bar()
                    continue
            return results
 
def write_results(results, string):
    current_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
    with open(f"{current_path}/{string}.txt", "a") as result_file:
        for result in results:
            result_file.write(f"{result}")
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            prog="log searcher",
            description="This module willl search into logs and return a file with the results")
    arg_parser.add_argument("-p", "--path", help="Path to the file you want to search in")
    arg_parser.add_argument("-s", "--string", help="String to search")
    args = arg_parser.parse_args()
    
    path = args.path
    string = args.string
 
    list_of_results = get_raw_data(path, string)
    if list_of_results != []:
        write_results(list_of_results, string)
    else:
        print("sorry, no matches found")
```

I have this code, but when I run the code, it shows an error. How can I fix it?

I'm trying to make searching algorithm. I received an order that is not related to this topic, and I have to use this app to automate it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\USER\Desktop\twitter\new\NEW\main.py", line 41, in <module>
    list_of_results = get_raw_data(path, string)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\USER\Desktop\twitter\new\NEW\main.py", line 8, in get_raw_data
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

What does this error mean? "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType"

Comment: How are you running this program? All we can say is that `args.path` is null.

Comment: Both `path` and `string` arguments aren't marked as "required", but further code expects them to not be `None`.  And you seem to run the scrips without any argument.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your problem like this:

```
 % python3 pathargs.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/a.py", line 22, in <module>
    list_of_results = get_raw_data(path, string)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/tmp/a.py", line 7, in get_raw_data
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

It is expected.  Here's the fix:

```diff
@@ -12,8 +12,10 @@
     arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
             prog="log searcher",
             description="This module willl search into logs and return a file with the results")
-    arg_parser.add_argument("-p", "--path", help="Path to the file you want to search in")
-    arg_parser.add_argument("-s", "--string", help="String to search")
+    arg_parser.add_argument("-p", "--path", required=True,
+                            help="Path to the file you want to search in")
+    arg_parser.add_argument("-s", "--string", required=True,
+                            help="String to search")
     args = arg_parser.parse_args()

     path = args.path
```

Basically I added two `required=True` aguments.

```shell
 % python3 pathargs.py
usage: log searcher [-h] -p PATH -s STRING
log searcher: error: the following arguments are required: -p/--path, -s/--string
```

Now the problem is obvious and handled correctly.